# Steam Client is not listing my game

Tags: steam, age-of-empires-online

For the first time I bought a game from steam `Age of Empires Online : All in wonder`. The transaction was successful and I got the game listed under my account in the steam website but when I download the latest steam client and install it, there are 0 games listed under the library tab. I also raised a steam support ticket three days ago, but no response from them till now. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you logged in to the correct account? Do you have "All games" (or something like that) instead of "Installed" selected in the drop down?

Comment: I am logged in to the correct account only and I have "All games" in the dropdown.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Age of Empires Online](http://store.steampowered.com/app/105430/) is a free-to-play game with optional pay-to-play DLC. The [All in Wonder bundle](http://store.steampowered.com/sub/13943/) is a bundle of this DLC for the base game. This might seem like a minor distinction, but it's an important to understand what's happening here.

As with other free-to-play games in Steam, the base Age of Empires Online game will not appear in the "All games" list like a normal purchased game would, even if have purchased DLC for it. However, if you go to the steam store and search for the game there, you will be able to install the game client through Steam as normal.

As your paid-for DLC is associated with your Steam account it should still be available when you log into AoE Online through Steam.

Comment: thanks for you answer. I did not know that.

Comment: The answer is no longer relevant as the game is no longer available to anyone (server closure).  Searching the Steam store for Age of Empires Online will not return any results.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean the Age of Empires Online: All in Wonder *Bundle?* This is treated as an item and may be added to your Steam Inventory rather than activating right away. You can access your inventory by going to the Community section and selecting the Inventory link. After that, select the item and select Activate (or something similar).

Answer (score 0):

I understand the question was asked when the servers were active, but just in case anyone missed out on the news the following answer may be relevant:

The game will no longer appear in Steam as the game servers are now closed.  According to the [Official Blog post](http://www.ageofempires.com/blog/?p=1109) the servers were closed down on 1st July 2014.

The game cannot be re-downloaded through Steam, and any instance of the game launcher will not work due to the server closure.